# Does Delphi Prism have Sleep() function?

Tags: .net, delphi-prism

I am coding in Delphi Prism and I need to pause a loop with sleep timer, but sleep(x) doesn't exist in Delphi prism. What function or procedure is there in Delphi prism to replace the sleep(x) procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: A word of caution: very few problems have calls to Sleep() as the solution.

Comment: I see. Then how would one go about pausing a while for instance.

Comment: why would you want to pause and completely block a thread? What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi Prism is using the .NET framework, so you should be able to use [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) instead of sleep(x);

Comment: I just tried Thread.Sleep and it won't work. My program is not pausing.

Comment: @digitalanalog: Thread.Sleep(x) is identical to sleep(x) - is your program using multiple threads?  Thread.Sleep() only pauses the executing thread, and it takes X as milliseconds...

Comment: I imported the system.Threading and called Thread.Sleep(1000); within a while loop. My program is not multi-threaded. The only thread is itself.

Comment: How do you know it didn't sleep for 1 second?  Were you trying to update some UI or something every second, because that probably wont work. (6 years ago?  I should stop clicking random questions!)